# Behavior of the temporary lobs after successful Oracle node fail-over

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

My application gets the following error when I'm trying to write data using the temporary lob created before the Oracle node fail-over.

```
ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
```

Please consider that the all the other cursors created before the fail-over works as expected, But not the blob writing using the above mentioned temporary lob.
Fail-over was completed successfully.

The application has created the temporary lob using following functions and bound to the database using OCIBindByPos.

```
OCIDescriptorAlloc
OCILobCreateTemporary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default lifetime of a temporary LOB is a session. Temporary LOBs are stored in Temporary Tablespace and transactions using temporary segments will not be fail over.

> #### ORA-22922 "nonexistent LOB value"
>
> **Cause:** The LOB value associated with the input locator does not exist.
>     The information in the locator does not refer to an existing LOB.
>
> **Action:** Repopulate the locator by issuing a select statement and retry the operation.

Comment: Thanks JSapkota, However my oracle session is recoved after the node fail-over and all the cursors are even valid after the fail-over. Only this lob locator has been invalidated.

Comment: Temporary LOBs are stored in Temporary tablespace and transactions using temporary segments will not be failover.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci07lob.htm#433719